# component does not display updated redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I have a Meals page with meal cards that toggles a modal with details about the clicked meal when the card is clicked:

```
{
  this.props.filteredMeals.map(m => {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.props.toggleMealModal(m)} key={m.id}>
        <MealCard meal={m} />
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

`toggleMealModal(meal)` updates the meal inside my redux store.

```
meal: {
  description: "Marre des sashimis de thon ou de saumon ? Tentez le maquereau!",
  fees: "80",
  id: 27,
  ingredients: "maquereau cru",
  name: "Sashimi de maquereau",
  no_fees_price: 599,
  original_price: 850,
}
```

inside my `MealModal` I have a `PaymentContainer` child component that also mounts when the modal is toggle and calls an action:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserCredit(this.props.meal.no_fees_price, this.props.meal.fees);
  }
```

where `this.props.meal` is fetched from my redux store via `mapStateToProps`.

the `getUserCredit()` is the following action:

```
export const getUserCredit = (noFeesPrice, fees) => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get('/get_user_credit')
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(setUserCredit(parseInt(res.data.credit) / 100));
      parseInt(noFeesPrice) + parseInt(fees) - parseInt(res.data.credit) < 0 ?
        dispatch(setMealPrice(0, (parseInt(noFeesPrice) + parseInt(fees)) / 100))
        :
        dispatch(setMealPrice((parseInt(noFeesPrice) + parseInt(fees) - parseInt(res.data.credit)) / 100, parseInt(res.data.credit) / 100)
          );
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

and then a child component displays the `mealPrice`, fetched from the redux store (and supposedly updated by `getUserCredit()`).

The problem is: the very first clicked meal card displays nothing at `this.props.mealPrice`, and when other cards are clicked and the modal mounts, `this.props.mealPrice` displays the price from the previously clicked meal card.

How can I change my code so that the right price mounts with the right meal ?

EDIT: relevant reducers and action creator code :

```
export const setUserCredit = (credit = 0) => ({
  type: SET_USER_CREDIT,
  payload: { credit }
});

export const setMealPrice = (mealPrice = null, amountOff = 0) => ({
  type: SET_MEAL_PRICE,
  payload: { mealPrice, amountOff }
});
```

---

```
case SET_USER_CREDIT: {
  return {
    ...state,
    credit: action.payload.credit
  }
}
case SET_MEAL_PRICE: {
  return {
    ...state,
    amountOff: action.payload.amountOff,
    mealPrice: action.payload.mealPrice
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the redux dev tools installed? Can you verify that every event is dispatched as expected?
Hint: you should probably dispatch using ```action.type``` instead of dispatching it directly.

Comment: @Neskews Hint: The OP is probably using action-creators in order to create the actions, not "dispatching directly".

Comment: When I `console.log` `credit` `mealPrice` and `amountOff` from the redux store in `componentDidMount` I get the values of the previously mounted mealModal. however, I can see in my redux dev tool that the values where correctly updated.

Comment: @Josep I agree. Though, I consider ```dispatch({ type: ACTION_TYPE, payload: PAYLOAD })``` better readable than ```dispatch(createAction(PAYLOAD))```.
However, we should concentrate on the OPs issue :P

Comment: @JulesCorb could you please share the code of the relevant reducer(s) and also the code of those action-creators?

Comment: @Josep, sure ! I update my post right now. btw what does OP means ?

Comment: @JulesCorb OP: Original Poster (please, add the code of the action-creators too, thanks!)

Comment: @Josep I just added it :)

Comment: I feel like the problem is that `getUserCredit()` was not completed before the `PaymentContainer` component mounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use status indicators while working with APIs.

Very simplified, you could build some action creators like:

```
const getUserCreditStart = () => ({
  type: GET_USER_CREDIT_START,
});

const getUserCreditSuccess = () => ({
  type: GET_USER_CREDIT_SUCCESS,
});

const getUserCreditError = payload => ({
  type: GET_USER_CREDIT_ERROR,
  payload,
});
```

In your `getUserCredit` function you can then dispatch these actions accordingly:

```
export const getUserCredit = (noFeesPrice, fees) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getUserCreditsStart());
    return axios.get('/get_user_credit')
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(setUserCredit(parseInt(res.data.credit) / 100));
        parseInt(noFeesPrice) + parseInt(fees) - parseInt(res.data.credit) < 0
        ? dispatch(setMealPrice(0, (parseInt(noFeesPrice) + parseInt(fees)) / 100))
        : dispatch(setMealPrice((parseInt(noFeesPrice) + parseInt(fees) - parseInt(res.data.credit)) / 100, parseInt(res.data.credit) / 100));
    })
    .then(() => dispatch(getUserCreditSuccess()))
    .catch(err => dispatch(getUserCreditError(err)))
}
```

And then, you need to add them to a reducer. Btw. typeToReducer might be a good choice here. :)

In the reducer you need to set the status on the different actions that got dispatched.

```
const initialState = {
  status: 'INITIAL',
};

...

case GET_USER_CREDIT_START: {
  return {
    ...state,
    status: 'START',
  }
}

case GET_USER_CREDIT_SUCCESS: {
  return {
    ...state,
    status: 'SUCCESS',
  }
}

case GET_USER_CREDIT_ERROR: {
  return {
    ...state,
    status: 'ERROR',
    error: action.payload,
  }
}
```

Well, and in your PaymentContainer component you then can wait for the answer and show a loading bar while you are waiting (the status information you get with mapStateToProps like you do with the results). In case of an error, you are able to display the error as well.